# Rails - How to show booking confirmation details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm currently building an Events app using rails and I'm struggling a little with the booking confirmation side and how to show this to a user who has booked to attend an event.

This is my code in the bookings_controller -

```
     class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!



    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user



    end

    def create

        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user

            if 
                @booking.paid_booking
                flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
                @booking.update_attributes!(booking_number: "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase)
                redirect_to event_booking_path(@event)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end
    end

    def free_booking
            if 
                @booking.free_booking
                @booking.update_attributes!(booking_number: "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase)
                redirect_to event_booking_path(@event)
            else
                flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
                render "new"
            end
    end

    def show
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new
        @booking = Booking.find_by(params[:booking_number])
    end

    def update
        puts params
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)


        if @booking.save
            redirect_to event_booking_path , notice: "Booking was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end




    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :booking_number, :quantity, :event_id, :stripe_charge_id, :total_amount)
    end



end
```

Here's the form view for both free & paid bookings -

**new.html.erb**

```
<% if @booking.free_booking %>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>



                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>
                    <% if @booking.errors.any? %>
                        <h2><%= pluralize(@booking.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this Booking from saving:</h2>
                  <ul>
                        <% @booking.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                      <li><%= message %></li>
                    <% end %>
                  </ul>
                <% end %>  

                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Please confirm the number of spaces you wish to reserve for this event.</p>
                    <%= form.input :quantity, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>  
                 <p> This is a free event. No payment is required.</p>

                   <div class="panel-footer"> 


                     <%= form.submit :submit, label: 'Confirm Booking', class: "btn btn-primary" %>

                     <% end %>
                  </div>                       


<% else %>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>



                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>

                 <div class="calculate-total">
                              <p>
                                  Confirm number of spaces you wish to book here:
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="1" name="booking[quantity]"  min="1" value="1" class="num-spaces">
                              </p>
                                <p>
                                    Total Amount
                                    £<span class="total" data-unit-cost="<%= @event.price %>">0</span>
                                </p>
                          </div>



                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my model -

**Booking.rb**

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user


  #before_create :set_booking_number 
  #before_validation :set_is_free
     validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
     validates :total_amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
     validates :quantity, :total_amount, :booking_number, presence: true

  def set_booking_number
    self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
  end

  def set_is_free
    set_is_free = total_amount.nil?
  end


  def free_booking
      self.valid?
        # Free events don't need to do anything special
          if event.is_free?

            save!
          end
  end



    def paid_booking
        # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
        self.valid?



                # Paid events should charge the customer's card
                #else

            begin
                        self.total_amount = event.price_pennies * self.quantity
                        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
                            amount: total_amount,
                            currency: "gbp",
                            source: stripe_token, 
                            description: "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}")
                        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
              self.booking_number = "MAMA" + '- ' + SecureRandom.hex(4).upcase
                        save!
                    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                    errors.add(:base, e.message)
                    false
                end
            #end 
        #end
  end
end
```

In my show views I have the following code for free bookings. In this instance I simply want to confirm (at this stage) the event title, quantity of spaces they've requested and the unique booking number -

```
                <h1>Hi there</h1>

                <p>You have placed a booking on <%= @event.title %>.</p>

                <p>You have reserved <%= @booking.quantity %> spaces for this event.</p>

                <p>Your booking number is <%= @booking.booking_number %></p>

                <p>We hope you have a wonderful time. Enjoy!</p>
```

At the moment, when I perform a test booking I get this in my views - 
[image: Booking confirmation]

So, basically, the specific details for quantity and number are not showing. In my bookings table I have an event_id and user_id. Even though each booking attracts an id I dont actually have booking_id as a column in my bookings table - does this make any difference?

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "stripe_token"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.integer  "quantity",         default: 1
    t.integer  "total_amount"
    t.string   "stripe_charge_id"
    t.string   "booking_number"
  end
```

I'm sure this is something so obvious but I'm failing to spot it. What am I missing?

Comment: I think @booking.quantity is nil please check this\

Comment: In my booking table its set as this - 't.integer  "quantity",         default: 1'

Comment: Check, (perhaps in a rails console) that the the particular booking referenced by booking_number in the params hash actually exists in your d/b. Also you can delete the second line in the show method.

Comment: I've looked via the console and I got this -    Booking.find_by(booking_number: "MAMA- 5D4EFC95")
  Booking Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "bookings".* FROM "bookings" WHERE "bookings"."booking_number" = ? LIMIT 1  [["booking_number", "MAMA- 5D4EFC95"]]
=> #<Booking id: 91, event_id: 22, user_id: nil, stripe_token: nil, created_at: "2016-11-11 20:52:51", updated_at: "2016-11-11 20:52:51", quantity: 2, total_amount: nil, stripe_charge_id: nil, booking_number: "MAMA- 5D4EFC95">

Comment: None of your booking attributes are being output, maybe try logging the @booking variable from the controller to ensure that it is what you expect it to be. Also have you setup any tests for that controller as that will also help you to debug.

Comment: No, I could place 'puts params' in there ? I've never done this before so I think I'm just being naive. My Events MVC is set up fairly similar and works fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `@booking` is persisted into the database. `new` creates the object but doesn't save it. Try using the `create` method which calls `new` then `save`

```
 def update
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])

        if @event.bookings.create(booking_params)
            redirect_to event_booking_path , notice: "Booking was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'new'
        end

end
```

**edit**
I would actually use `new` and then `save` like so

```
     def update
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)


        if @booking.save
            redirect_to event_booking_path , notice: "Booking was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'new'
        end

end
```

The `save` method will return with true or false if the object was saved or not, the result of this can be used in the conditional.

`Create` on the other hand will return the model regardless of whether the object was saved or not. Which means the if statement will always be true.

So, using `new` + `save` will allow you to actually see if the booking was saved or not or if another error occurred.

Comment: Should this actually go in my 'show' method? Rather than 'update'? I've wondered if its my 'show' method that I'm wrong on here.

Comment: It should be in the `update` method as it is where the form posts the data for processing.

Comment: No, that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: could you try my updated answer? If that doesn't work try logging  `params` object to see if your data is actually being posted correctly

Comment: I've tried the updated answer and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: If this is still a problem, could you update your question with your form and maybe your route?

Comment: I've included the full controller & model code for Booking along with the forms for both free and paid bookings. I think the issue here may be that I'm attempting to make a distinction between the two but I'm missing some components within the MVC in order to incorporate this correctly.

Comment: For example, the validations in the model fail when I attempt a free booking so I need to put some extra code in there so the validations can pass whether a user books a free and/or paid event.

Comment: Hmm, could you maybe in the update method in the controller try `@event.save` instead of `@booking.save`. Also, no errors in console? No rogue bookings created with no parent event? If `@bookings.save` works then something is being persisted into the database or failing somewhere. Lastly can I see an example result of the `puts params`? thanks

Comment: Rogue bookings? Yes, I think I'm getting those - why does that happen?

Comment: Whereabouts in the controller shall I place 'puts params'?

Comment: I've also added my bookings table - does it matter that I don't have booking_id as a column?

Comment: Place `pp params` (pp stands for pretty print) in the first line of the update method in the controller, in your server log you should find the dump of params. What happens when you use `@event.save` instead of `@booking.save` in the update controller? The rouge bookings are happening because somehow the events were not added to them when it was saving. From the rails console try doing the following `Booking.count` then submit the form and run it again and see if the number increases?

Comment: When I use pp params in the update I get an argument error - wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0). Nothing changes with @event.save. Booking.count increased by 2 bookings with ONE submission of the form.

Comment: thats really strange about `pp`

Comment: try `puts params.inspect` within update method. If the booking saves what is in the event_id column? also why is there two bookings?